# Fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: php

I am getting a fatal error from my image resize script that takes jpegs and resizes them and then saves. The image I am uploading are not over the max upload limit (not ever close) and based on the error I am not close to the limit.

**Am I missing something about how the memory is used and why it would fail randomly but work on images that are larger?**

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 52428800 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 15756 bytes) in /home/content/t/w/e/myserver/html/test/includes/resize_class.php on line 34
```

I have a php.ini file in the same directory

```
memory_limit = 50M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 192M
```

LINE 34:  `$this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);`

resize_calss.php:
Also to note. The user is uploading up to 3 iamges at a time and I am looping through and using this class to resize and save the thumbs on my server

```
/*
* File: SimpleImage.php
* Author: Simon Jarvis
* Copyright: 2006 Simon Jarvis
* Date: 08/11/06
* Link: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php
*
* This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
* modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
* as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
* of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
*
* This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
* but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
* MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the
* GNU General Public License for more details:
* http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html
*
*/

class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {

      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {

         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {

      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {

      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {

      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
   }      

}
?>
```

Comment: Show us the function in *resize_class.php* that contains line 34, and then people can try to help you. How are we supposed to debug code we can't see? :)

Comment: Have you run an xDebug trace to see what is taking all the memory?  Maybe you can find the leak so you can stay under the 50MB limit you exceeded?

Comment: Sorry about that see edit above regarding line 34. I will take a look at xDebug

Comment: @Denoteone I believe the request was for the entire function / method containing line #34. A single line isn't going to help much though at a guess, I'd say you're not cleaning up resources, eating more memory each time you use `imagecreatefromjpeg()`

Comment: @Phil the full script has been added. I also noted that I am looping through the script and using the class multiple times each time the page is submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something I've done in my [image manipulation class](https://gist.github.com/880506) that this one does not do is destroy the original image after creating a new one (such as in the `resize()` method).

Try changing the `resize()` method to this

```
function resize($width,$height) {
    $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());

    imagedestroy($this->_image);

    $this->image = $new_image;
}
```

I'd also add something similar in the `load()` method

```
function load($filename) {
    if (is_resource($this->image)) {
        imagedestroy($this->image);
    }

    // and the rest
}
```

Answer (score 2):

image re-size will used lots memory, 
you can consider to use `ini_set` to boost the memory limit 
specifically at the method (doing resize) in resize_class.php

related questions

- [Efficient JPEG Image Resizing in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661/efficient-jpeg-image-resizing-in-php)
- [reasonable PHP memory_limit for image resize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/527532/reasonable-php-memory-limit-for-image-resize)
- [an enthusiasm guy who create a memory calculator for this](http://www.dotsamazing.com/en/labs/phpmemorylimit)

Answer (score 0):

Your script seems to have exceeded the `memory limit`.  (52,428,800 bytes = 50MB)

Comment: This is the first comment on this answer

Comment: @Phil "...based on the error I am not close to the limit." <-- the OP seems not understanding what the `50M` means in the `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

post_max_size shall be graeter than or equal to upload_max_filesize in php.ini

```
post_max_size = 200M
upload_max_filesize = 192M
```