# Codeigniter rotate large images

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, rotation, gd

i have a problem in codeigniter rotating large images...bigger than 1.2mb.
for smaller images, there is no problem.

here is the code:

```
public function rotate(){
    $path = $this->input->post('path');
    $file = $this->input->post('file');
    $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $config['source_image'] = $path;
    $config['rotation_angle'] = '90';
    $config['new_image'] = './uploads/_rot'.$file;
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
    //$this->image_lib->rotate();
    if(!$this->image_lib->rotate()){
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    } else {
        echo 'OK';
    }
}
```

Comment: what kind of problem? Post the error messages

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to low [`memory_limit`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.memory-limit) setting in PHP core (you can verify it with [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/phpinfo)) and the memory consumption by [GD2 library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).
You can consult these two questions on fixing that:

- [PHP GD Allowed memory size exhausted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2827908/php-gd-allowed-memory-size-exhausted)
- [A fail-safe way to prevent GD image library from running out of memory? (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117344/a-fail-safe-way-to-prevent-gd-image-library-from-running-out-of-memory-php)

You can also give it a try with [ImageMagic library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php):

```
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
$config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin/convert';
```

Make sure it's [installed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php) before.

Answer (score 1):

i have located the problem. thanks Struna.
my hosting provider have set php memory limit to 32mb and gd2 libs are hungry for mem, and they are not going to increase it, 
solution is to migrate or another library: imagemagick :)
here is the code and it works great

```
public function rotate(){
    $path = $this->input->post('path');
    $file = $this->input->post('file');
    //echo "aaa";
    $config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
    $config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin';       
    $config['source_image'] = $path;
    $config['rotation_angle'] = '90';
    $config['quality'] = "90%";     
    $config['new_image'] = './uploads/_rot'.$file;
    $this->load->library('image_lib');
    $this->load->helper('file');

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config); 
    //$this->image_lib->rotate();
    if(!$this->image_lib->rotate()){
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    } else {
        echo 'OK';
        //delete_files($path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. [You can accept your own answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions) since your solution solves the problem.