# how to resize the image while uploading using php

Tags: php

Please help with the php code to upload an image. The image should be compressed while uploading without disturbing its resolution. Also, the image should be resized in 500 x 500 px. Any assistance will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: have a look here http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/resize-image-while-upload-using-php.html

Comment: dupe of a bizzilion questions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Resize image on upload php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612289/resize-image-on-upload-php)

Comment: Soooooo..  Welcome to SO, read the FAQ before asking a question etc, add code of what you've tried bla bla bla, better luck next time .

Answer (score 1):

```
function resize_image($file, $width, $height) {
    list($w, $h) = getimagesize($file);
    /* calculate new image size with ratio */
    $ratio = max($width/$w, $height/$h);
    $h = ceil($height / $ratio);
    $x = ($w - $width / $ratio) / 2;
    $w = ceil($width / $ratio);
    /* read binary data from image file */
    $imgString = file_get_contents($file);
    /* create image from string */
    $image = imagecreatefromstring($imgString);
    $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
    imagecopyresampled($tmp, $image,
    0, 0,
    $x, 0,
    $width, $height,
    $w, $h);
    imagejpeg($tmp, $file, 100);
    return $file;
    /* cleanup memory */
    imagedestroy($image);
    imagedestroy($tmp);
}
```

you can call the function like this :

```
resize_image($_FILE["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], 500, 500);
```

See more info [here](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/03/resize-image-while-upload-using-php.html)

Comment: Note also that the code after the return statement will never be executed.