# imagecreatefromjpeg is causing memory error

Tags: php, upload

I am getting a memory error:

```
Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 67633152) (tried to allocate 19104 bytes)
```

I've done a ton of research. I tried to increase memory limit on php.ini to 256M and checked that with phpinfo() to verify it had changed. This did not work.

My image is a big one at 9.6M with 4776px × 2856px res. I know that uploaded images get bloated up to around possibly: 4776x2856x3 = 40M+. But this is well below the memory limit of 256M. I have even tried with a set memory limit of 10000M. This did not work either.

I uploaded other smaller images that worked fine but then retried the big image with no success and no change to error message.

What is my next step?

Here is a slimmed down version of my upload code:

```
foreach(array_keys($FILES['name']) as $KEY) {

if($FILES['type'][$KEY] === 'image/jpeg') {
    $TEMP = imagecreatefromjpeg($FILES['tmp_name'][$KEY]);
} else if($FILES['type'][$KEY] === 'image/png') {
    $TEMP = imagecreatefrompng($FILES['tmp_name'][$KEY]);
} else if($FILES['type'][$KEY] === 'image/gif') {
    $TEMP = imagecreatefromgif($FILES['tmp_name'][$KEY]);
} else {
    die(); }

$HD = $KEY.'.jpeg';
imagejpeg($TEMP, $HD, 100);

imagedestroy($TEMP); 
}
```

Here is my php.ini

INPUT:

```
post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M
max_file_uploads = 200
memory_limit = 1024M
max_execution_time = 259200
max_input_time = 259200
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1200
```

Comment: Can you limit the max_upload_size? The image libary was not created to handle such large images.

Comment: You could also use getimagesize() to determine whether the picture is too memory heavy to pass on to imagecreatefrom*(). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6128013/possible-to-check-if-imagecreatefromjpeg-is-going-to-cause-memory-exhausted-fata?rq=1

Comment: I used that and got a number around 54561024. Which is still below my memory limit of 1024M currently set. How do I know its too memory heavy? By using memory limit as a reference? Im not sure what to do anymore with this except for limit users to small images, which is not ideal.

Comment: So it turns out that my hosting package is to blame. phpinfo() != hosting package limits. My RAM is 0.3 GB = 300MB which would probably where the problem lies. Yet 300 MB is still enough for the 60MB that's required. I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1):

Changing memory limit would help in many cases except mine. I just read on my host that even though changing memory limit does reflect in phpinfo(); it is not the real limit imposed by the host which may be different.

> Due to resource limits on our Shared Hosting machines, it is not
>   possible to allocate more memory to PHP than the maximum for your
>   package. Using a php.ini file or the memory_limit directive to
>   increase memory for PHP may result in the phpinfo() output reflecting
>   the change however the server will not allocate more memory than the
>   limit imposed