# Php code interrupt if Imagick::pingImage() return false

Tags: php, imagick

```
<?php
   $im = new Imagick();
   if ($im->pingImage('1.jpg')) {
       $image_info = $im->identifyImage();
       print_r($image_info);
   }
   else {
       echo 'image doesn't exist';
   }
?>
```

If I pass to `pingImage` a real image name, then `print_r` shows an array with parameters. But if I pass to `pingImage` not a real image name, nothing happens, but I expect output of "image doesn't exist". At the same time if I add an `echo` output **before** the condition, this `echo` does work.

Generally code is working until `pingImage` return `false`.

I haven't find the answer in the Imagick documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4613341/678026
All I needed to do is to apply **try - catch** construction:

```
$im = new Imagick();
try {
    $im->pingImage('3.jpg');
}
catch(ImagickException $e) {
    echo "image doesn't exist";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You got syntax error in your code, in else clause. it should be:

```
echo "image doesn't exist";
```

or

```
echo 'image doesn\'t exist';
```

(event SO highlighting should tell you there's something wrong :). And make your code more clear and use `file_exists()` first to see if what you expect to be file name really points to a file you can access:

```
if( file_exists( $fileName ) ) {
   $im = new Imagick();
   if ($im->pingImage( $fileName )) {
       $image_info = $im->identifyImage();
       print_r($image_info);
   } else {
     printf("Can't get image attributes of %s", htmlspecialchars( $fileName ));

   }
} else {
   printf("Can't open file %s", htmlspecialchars( $fileName ));
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry, I typed 'image doesn't exist' just for example, in my real code it was '11111' )

Comment: Thank you for the answer!
But if a file exists it fails again. For example if I have a broken or empty file "fake-jpg.jpg". Function `file_exists` return `true`, but `pingImage` stops execution of code.

Comment: Well, one guess it that `pingImage` is simply buggy. It looks like elementary bug, but still. And you can check its sources to ensure. Or, depending on how problematic it is for you, simple workaround would be to check file size too prior calling `pingImage` or check output to see if it is valid.

Comment: As it turned out the case was in try - catch. Anyway thank you for help.

Comment: Yep, PHP manual sucks sometimes, so please go to http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.pingimage.php and put a comment for reference (and to save others' time)