# Resize image php

Tags: php, resize, height, width, png

I've been searching all over the places on how to resize an image depending on the max-height and max-width I provided. I have tried SimpleImage.php (http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/articles/php-image-resizing.php), ImageMagician (http://phpimagemagician.jarrodoberto.com/), and so on. But they all failed to accomplished my task.

My main goal is to resize an image (**NOT crop**) depending on the max-height and max-width I provided. Can anyone please guide me through this?

Comment: There are lots of questions on this already on stack overflow

Comment: If you don't mind, can you provide any reference?

Comment: http://snipplr.com/view/64732/

Comment: here's the first thing that came up in a search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661/efficient-jpeg-image-resizing-in-php

Comment: all of your references didn't even mention anything about max-width or max-height